# AWS Marketplace Catalog API - possible entity types for products to be used with ListEntities action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace, amazon-marketplace

I need to understand what products are supported by ListEntities action in AWS Marketplace Catalog API. Action requires [EntityType parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/API_ListEntities.html#API_ListEntities_RequestSyntax) to be submitted.

From the perspective of documentation - it is specified, that only [AMI and container products are supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/seller-products.html) - those are mapped to AmiProduct and ContainerProduct entity types.

However, after some research and guessing - I've discovered following additional entity types to be supported there:

- SaaSProduct
- DataProduct
- ProfessionalServicesProduct
- ServerProduct

Does anybody know if there are further entity types for products supported there?